# monaca デバッカーでのみ has no method 'remove' となる

Tags: monaca

Monaca Cloud IDE のプレビューではエラーにならずに思うように動くのですが、
Androidの実機デバッカーで動かすと以下のようなエラーが出ます。
どう対処すれば良いのでしょうか？

```
var tmplNode = document.getElementById("id01");
tmplNode.remove();
```

↓

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'remove'

Answer (score 2):

DOMのElementに`remove()`関数がある保障はありません。ブラウザの問題ですね。
実際に出ているエラーの内容は
`Object # has no method 'remove'`
`Objectにremove関数が無いよ`
……と怒られています。
削除するのであれば親要素を参照して、子要素(自分)を消すのが早いですね
`removeChild`か`textContent`・`innerText`・`innerHTML`を`null`で上書きすれば子要素は消えます。
[本家SOの回答を抜粋](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561277/)しますが、関数作って消したほうが楽ですかね。

```js
function removeElement(element) {
  element && element.parentNode && element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

setTimeout(function(){
  removeElement(document.getElementById("goodbye"));
},1000);
```

```html
<div onclick="removeElement(this)">クリックできえる</div>
<div id="goodbye">初期化できえる</div>
```

Comment: 環境によって使えないメソッドがあるのですね。修正したところ思った通り実行できました。